# OmegaT: How to import already translated files?

Tags: import, language-translation

My team has been using Notepad for translation purposes so far. Recently, we decided to use one of the CAT tools available on the Internet - OmegaT.

We've got source and manually translated files, and only values were ever touched.

Is it possible to import both to the same project, so that source phrases stay source, and our phrases become their translated counterparts?

Note: I don't know if it matters, but files are formatted as INI (key=value).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With currently Beta version of 4.* releases (currently 4.1.5), you can use nice visual aligner - https://www.proz.com/forum/omegat_support/306343-new_interactive_aligner_in_omegat.html

Comment: Cool they made something like this!

Answer (score 2):

What you need is an alignment. It takes source and target files and creates a translation memory.

In your specific case (INI files), you can use OmegaT to do an automatic alignment with a command line:
http://omegat.sourceforge.net/manual-standard/en/chapter.installing.and.running.html#omegat.command.arguments

Sample command line:
java -jar OmegaT.jar "C:\OmegaTProject" --mode=console-align --alignDir="C:\OmegaTProject\align"

For more general purposes, and with a GUI, there's a prototype version of OmegaT with an aligner:
https://omegat.ci.cloudbees.com/job/omegat-prototype/26/

See the OmegaT development mailing list for information about this.

Didier